# how to split string between two characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

How to split target string betweeen `/#/` and `/` chars?

```
http://www.site.com/#/target/
```

The output is supposed to be `target`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the string 'target' isn't in the source string.

Comment: For instance, `string.split('/#/').pop().split('/')[0];`

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: if it's for urls, there are other (better?) ways than regex (for example location.hash).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle for the regex required to match the text between the last two slashes:

http://jsfiddle.net/7BGP5/

The code is quite simple:

```
var str = "http://www.site.com/#/target/";
var regexp = /.*\/(.*?)\//;
console.log(str.match(regexp)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `replace` with regular expression:

```
"http://www.site.com/#/target/".replace(/.*#\/([^/]+).*/, "$1");
// >> "target"
```